# DNS Migration from 2K12 dc to 2k22 dc

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I am upgrading two domain controllers from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2022.

I have created two Windows Server 2022 servers, and am migrating the roles. The old servers have AD DS and DNS roles. The SYSVOL replication type is DFSR.

My plan is to join the new server to domain, add the AD DS role, promote them to the DC, and transfer the FSMO roles.

What do I need to do in order to successfully migrate the DNS role?

The IP addresses of the old servers will be reused, since we have unknown systems with the DNS servers IP hardcoded on them.

Comment: This is more than DNS. By far the best way is to replace the existing DCs with the same name and IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the DNS zone file(s) for Active Directory are going to be replicating in Active Directory. Unless you're using a text-based zone file, there is nothing to migrate, in terms of DNS records. There are some other things to consider, especially when you're re-using existing IPs:

- You'll need to use temporary IP addresses for your new servers, and they'll need to point to the DNS services of your existing servers to find the domain, etc.
- In the DNS server properties, note any per-server customizations, such as what you may be forwarding to (such as your ISP's IP addresses)
- You may also have conditional forwarders. These can be configured to replicate in Active Directory like the zone file, but this may not be the case for you.
- When you switch around the IP addresses, you'll want to make sure the records are able to be updated correctly. A PTR record, for example, may not let the new server update the previous record, since it did not create it. In such a case, just delete the record and let AD put it back.

Keep in mind that the netlogon service is whats responsible for creating all of the AD records. Restart that service if you want to force it to update/make new records. However the hostname of the server itself is registered with the DNS settings on the adapter. You can use `ipconfig /registerdns` to update those.